# Is there a way to create my own ideavim plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, vim-plugin, ideavim

I would like to use with my emulated vim in jetbrain's IDE, some plugins that can be used with the original vim.

But as far as I know, only a small handful of plugins are compatible with ideaVim.

So I wonder how these plugins have been made, and if it is possible to make my own.

I can't find any documentation about such a thing on the internet.

Does somebody know?

Comment: You can try to inspect the plugin's sources. Go to https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?search=vim select the needed plugin, scroll the page till the end, and click on `Source Code` if this option is presented.

Comment: Vim plugins are mainly written in Vim's own scripting language, which is not fully supported by IdeaVim. Any way you look at it, you will have to reimplement those Vim plugins. @EgorKlepikov's suggestion of looking at the source code of existing plugins sounds like the best available strategy.